# postfix to send email from a client

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

I own a domain `company.com`. All employees in `company` have gmail accounts. The domain registrar already provides email forwarding, so if I were to send something to `bob@company.com`, it would be forwarded to `bob@gmail.com` since I defined it in the web ui.

Now the issue is how can `bob` send an email from `bob@company.com`? In gmail, you can add an email account as an alias like so:[image], but how can make the backend using `postfix`? I've read lots of guides, and can't find any information to do this specifically. Some guides tell me how to do it from only one user account, from the shell only, or offloads the task to another smtp server. This is NOT what I want.

Potential answers I have found:
http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailclients.html
This requires a linux account on the server as well. What if I want to have another domain's email forwarded too?

Comment: I do know how to use linux. I also know how to start the server. I am able to send emails from the command line as the user I'm currently logged in as, but I don't know what to do next. I'm using amazon ec2 instance and I have port 587 open. EDIT: wow that guy deleted his comment. In summary, he assumed I didn't try anything.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Say `bob@company.com` receives a mail which gets forwarded to `bob@gmail.com` and user wants to reply as `bob@company.com` from his gmail account? is it?

Comment: yes, this is what I want.

Comment: Do you have a postfix server which can send mails for `bob@company.com`?

Comment: yes. I can do it from the command line, but I don't know the next steps to set up things like tls, and creating multiple users with passwords to feed to the email client for authentication.

Comment: So here are the things you will need to do. 1) setting up [SASL auth](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) for users. 2) setting up [TLS](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html) 3) Configuring your postfix to listen on a public address 4) Configuring gmail to use it. I would suggest you to do one at a time and incase you are stuck,post your `postconf -n` output as separate question and people here will be able to help better.